# I want Discord bot to write another python script output with comand

Tags: python, scripting, command, discord

I did build a discord bot and i want to add a command that run & read another script output in python
how i can do that ?
here is my new bot on discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

flashing = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@flashing.command()

async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(flashing.latency * 1000)} ms' )
    print('bot is ready.')

@flashing.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()


flashing.run('token')
```

the other script name is base_script.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the two scripts are in the same folder:

```
#scripts.py
def Some_Code():
    #Put all of scripts.py code in this function
    return(Variables)
    #make sure to return all variable that you want to read in your other file
```

assuming you've set up `scripts.py` like that, the rest is easy:

```
import scripts
print(scripts.Some_Code())
```

Comment: the script can read the other script now but how do I make command to use it and print it as command i am bad with this and i don't understand this part

Comment: I'm not really understanding your problem, maybe update your question with the code from both files, and explain what code you are trying to run?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721901/make-a-command-to-discord-bot-on-python-from-another-script-i-did-import-it-bas
Check here